# How to undo cmd command for jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, pandas, cmd, jupyter-notebook

I ran this line in my cmd which is directed in the path of python:

```
jupyter notebook --NotebookApp.iopub_data_rate_limit=1e10
```

and now my pandas is not working anymore in my jupyter notebook.

Does anyone know how to fix this solution? Or perhaps is there a way to undo this line of code?